# Update oracle table and change one character with another

Tags: sql, oracle, function, replace

I have this table where one of the Fields contains values like this `¤1¤`. It is in an *Unicode database and nvarchar2 Fields*.

I then want to switch the `¤` With an ? and Write this line:

```
update table1 set col1 = REPLACE(col1,'¤','?');

commit;
```

The col1 is not updated.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ascii('¤') from dual;
```

Even though this states 164 as the result on a non-unicode database, it doesn't so on a unicode database. Hence the replace as asked for, will not work.

```
select chr(164 USING NCHAR_CS) from dual;
```

Using this states '¤' as the result.

Hence the following replace should work.

```
select replace(col1, chr(164 USING NCHAR_CS), chr(63)) from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime simple cut and paste may not get the character properly in your query so .. instead of writing the character in your query.. get the ascii value (you can use **ascii** or **dump** function in oracle to get the ascii value of the character) of the character and then use that in your replace as below

Your character seems to me ASCII value 164 ...

```
-- try as below
update table1 set col1 = replace(col1,chr(164),'?'); 
commit;
```